# Mysql self join and calculate SUM with group by

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask

I have a game1 table,
it seems like this:

| player1 | player2 | result_1 | result_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team1 | team2 | 10 | 5 |
| team1 | team3 | 10 | 5 |
| team2 | team3 | 11 | 2 |

result_1 is player1's result and result_2 is player2's result.

I want to make below table:

| player | result |
| --- | --- |
| team1 | 20 |
| team2 | 16 |
| team3 | 7 |

team1's result : 10 + 10
team2's result : 5 + 11
team3's result : 5 + 2

Comment: You can UNION ALL to get (team, result). And then GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses a union:

```sql
SELECT player, SUM(result) AS result
FROM
(
    SELECT player1 AS player, result_1 AS result FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT player2, result_2 FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY player;
```

Comment: wow!!!!! I've been thinking about it all day. Thank you!!!